# Commerce Kickstart "Add product" does not give option to assign it a product catalog

Tags: commerce, taxonomy-terms

I just started using "Drupal commerce kickstart" and i've created an new product variation type. When I'm adding a new product of a specific type, it doesnt give me the option to setup its "product catalog". The default generated product types offer the option to set up the products catalog, but for manualy created ones it doesnt give me the option. Instead it gives me "menu setting". Am I missing a step here?

[image]
[image]